# Mocking $interval

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to mock $interval service, here is my controller code,

```
$interval(function() {
$scope.myFunction();
}, 300000);
```

I would like to write a jasmine test and fire the interval,

```
var $interval;
inject(function(_$interval_) {
$interval =  _$interval_;
});

it("Test case",function(){
$interval.flush(30000);
});
```

When i ran the above test case, $interval in controller is not firing. Am I missing anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`$interval` has a mock implementation in [angular-mocks](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js).

The mock version of `$interval` has a [flush](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L526) method for controlling ticks

Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/98Xhr/)

Comment: I followed the same and when I call flush(), the control goes to flush method defined in angular.mocks, which has 'now += milliesIPassed;' in its first line.  here now is holding 'Nan', because of this my callback is not firing.

Comment: Can you provide sample fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
var $interval, futurems = 30001;
inject(function(_$interval_) {
   $interval =  _$interval_;
});

it("Test case",function(){
    $interval.flush(futurems);
});
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.